# How do I make SVG wrapper with custom border responsive so that it automatically scales?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to work with custom border

```css
html, body {
  background: rgb(20,20,20);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.svg-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
      margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;  
}
.shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 140 540;
  stroke-dashoffset: -474;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #19f6e8;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  transition: stroke-width 1s, stroke-dashoffset 1s, stroke-dasharray 1s;
}
.text {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
}
.svg-wrapper:hover .shape {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 760;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect class="shape" height="60" width="320" />
    <div class="text">ZACH SAUCIER</div>
  </svg>
</div>
```

How do I make this SVG wrapper responsive to different devices?

No matter what I do with it, it doesn't scale if I resize the container

Comment: give the svg root element a viewBox attribute

Comment: Could you please help me how to do it? I'm newbie in websiting

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox